# putty connection timeout - how to troubleshoot

Tags: ssh

when i try to make a ssh connection (port 22) connection to a server in my college it's giving "network error- connection timed out" error. I'm connected to internet through my home wifi. Then, I went to my friend's home any tried to establish the same connection, it worked fine. Is This the problem with my router or internet connection. please help me in troubleshooting.

PS. None of my roommates were able to establish the ssh connection in my home wifi.

Comment: how do you get the IP for the college server ?

Comment: college provided me both the ip and hostname

Comment: what I'm thinking is maybe these servers are behind some router/gateway and that the IP resolves to the gateway not a certain computer, are you sure that this isn't whats happening ? what happens when you browse that IP ?

Comment: i'm not sure of that .. but if thats the case it should block when i'm  connecting from different wifi network . My friends were able to connect to it in their wifi, even when i go to their house i'm able to connect. its only when i'm connected to my wifi the problem occurs

Comment: Do you have root in the server? I'd suggest to change port number and try again, might be an ISP issue

Answer (score 1):

"network error- connection timed out" I usually get either when I am not able to ping the SSH Server(connectivity issue) or IPtables on server is blocking my connection.

Comment: but i get this error only in my home wifi. if i connect to other wifi  i dont get this problem